# Bind database to existing JBDC Connection

Tags: java, mysql

I'm making a Java MySQL CLI and I'm having problems with the database selection. When I connect to a database server, I don't include a database

```
Console console = System.console();
String host = console.readLine("MySQL Host: ");
host = "jdbc:mysql://"+host+":3306/";
```

Because I want users to be able to select a database themselves. I have a `listDatabases` function that works perfectly fine but if I want to query a table I get the following error:

```
Jan 13, 2015 4:06:40 PM com.user.package.MySQL listTables
SEVERE: No database selected
java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:996)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2484)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1446)
    at com.user.package.MySQL.listTables(MySQL.java:92)
    at com.user.package.MySQL.select(MySQL.java:81)
    at com.user.package.Main.main(Main.java:52)
```

When a user selects a table the following function gets executed:

```
public void useDatabase() {
    Statement useStatement = null;
    ResultSet use = null;
    String database = this.getDatbase();
    try {
        useStatement = this.getCon().createStatement();
        use = useStatement.executeQuery("USE "+database);
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(MySQL.class.getName());
        lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
}
```

The `getCon` function simply returns the current database connection.

But that apparently doesn't do the trick. Any thoughts?

Comment: see edit to my answer

Comment: FWIW, I would have the `useDatabase()` function take the DB name as a parameter, and only on success then fill in your classes' `database` field.

Comment: I have a select database function that only let's the user select existing databases and then save it as a class variable so useDatabase can just do `this.getDatabase().setCatalog(this.database)` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the `USE` command is connection-specific - if you request a new connection with the `getCon` method and it's then disposed of then the next (new) connection will revert back to having no selected schema.

An alternate JDBC function to select the schema to be used on an existing connection is this:

```
connection.setCatalog(databaseName);
```

Comment: getCon is a function that I created myself which returns the current Connection object. The same connection is used everywhere

Comment: @RoemerBakker fair enough - without the implementation of `getCon()` it was impossible to tell.

Answer (score 0):

DB connection string must contain also the schema name like: 
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" - test is the schema name.

Under one Mysql instance there can be several databases, notice that.

Comment: Can you explain how the schema table helps me to select a different database?

Comment: I see but as described, this is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. The problem is that I can't change the database on an existing connection object

Comment: you have to select a database, either it's yours or either it's Mysql's

Comment: I'm not so sure because I can make connections and execute non-table specific queries just fine

Comment: I've got code that connects perfectly happily using a schema-less JDBC URI.